# Secure methods using SpringBoot and Keycloak

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, keycloak

The "demo" configuration for securing app in Keycloak is like this:

```
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name = edit
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].authRoles[0] = edit
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /api/edit/*

keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[1].name = view
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[1].authRoles[0] = view
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[1].patterns[0] = /api/view/*
```

But I don't want to use securing by path, but rather by methods (generally POST, PUT and DELETE available for "edit", GET for "view"). Is it even possible? I tried with pure Spring Data solutions, but Keycloak doesn't seem to work fine with that.

Answer (score 2):

you can specify methods in the security constraints, like : 
    keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].methods[0] = GET

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that tomorrow! Could you please specify the source where you got that information from? I wasn't able to find any documentation.

Comment: check this class https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/adapters/oidc/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springboot/KeycloakSpringBootConfiguration.java but I will update the documentation tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

you can add method level security in your spring boot application.

you just need to add `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` in method level.
to use method level security you need to add

`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
                              prePostEnabled = true,
                              securedEnabled = true,
                              jsr250Enabled = true)`

in securityconfig class level.